# Windows Phone 8.1 RT ColorAnimation

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, storyboard, winrt-xaml

I got a `ControlTemplate` with `TargetProperty="Button"` which uses a `VisualStateManager` and everything works fine except the `ColorAnimation` for the `BitmapIcon.Foreground` property.

I've set it like this:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Icon" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(BitmapIcon.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                To="Green"
                Duration="0:0:0.100" />
```

Nothing happens when i press the button. All the other `ColorAnimations` in the `StoryBoard` for the given `VisualState` works like a charm.

Setting it the old way works from events in the codebehind but its alot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color animation for the above code because foreground property of bitmapicon comes from iconelement class.

Try the following code:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Icon" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(IconElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
            To="Green"
            Duration="0:0:0.100" />
```

Hope it works like charm. :)

Comment: may be you can have bitmapicon as button's content and try animating color of button's content presenter.

Comment: I used objectanimationusingkeyframe for animating the forground. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Setup `EnableDependentAnimation` to `True`

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Icon" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(BitmapIcon.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                To="Green"
                EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                Duration="0:0:0.100" />
```